# Jquery UI Accordian not starting collapsed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion

I'm using the Jquery UI According and it's not starting all collapsed.

Here is the code I have:

```
$j(function() {
    $j( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
      active: false
    });

});
```

Reading the API documentation on this, it says I must have the collapsible set to TRUE in order for the active: False to work properly.  I have that.  But when I view the according on my site, the 1st item isn't collapsed - it's open.

Where did I go wrong in the code?

Thanks in advance for your reply.

Comment: add semi-colon between `collapsible: true` and `active: false`

Comment: @JonathandeM. Not semi-colon, it needs a comma

Comment: Thank you.  the comma worked.

Comment: and why I'm using the $j.  Not quite sure.  Someone else did the JavaScript.  This is my entire script:  $j=jQuery.noConflict()
$j(function() {
    $j( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true,
      active: false
    });

});  (and I'm using this script file:  http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js)

Comment: and how do you put a line break when commenting/replying here?  I can only type run-on sentences...if I press enter, it saves my comment/reply.

Comment: You can't put line breaks here

Comment: Do you use the javascript console? Ctrl+shift+J in chrome. It usually will throw errors like "Unexpected end" or "expected )" for things like this. Useful for debugging.

Comment: CRLT-Shift-J in Chrome...I like that!  didn't know that existed.  This will come in handy.  Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `,` to separate options.

```
$j=jQuery.noConflict();

$j(function() {

$j("#accordion").accordion({
collapsible: true,
active: false
});
});
```

[Sample](http://jsbin.com/iquhih/1/edit)